# Transactions in camel routes with Splitter parallel processing

Tags: java, transactions, apache-camel, jbossfuse, apache-servicemix

We have an XML file which consists of multiple customer elements in it and we want to save customer information to the DB using transactions. From my understanding, transactions needs to be run in a single thread to roll back the whole transaction in case of errors.

Here's my XML:

```
<root>
    <customers>
        <customer>...</customer>
        <customer>...</customer>
        <customer>...</customer>
        <customer>...</customer>
    </customers
</root>
```

Here is my route:

```
<route id="routeA">
    <from uri="direct-vm:sample" />
    <transacted />
    <splitter parallelProcessing = "true" stopOnException="true"
            strategyRef="combine" />
    <xpath>/root/customers/customer</xpath>
    <bean ref="customerService" method="saveCustomer" />
    <onException>java.lang.Exception</onException>
    <handled><constant>true</constant></handled>
    <rollback markRollbackOnly="true" />
</route>
```

The method `saveCustomer()` runs a lot of business logic before saving customers to the Database and if for some reason an exception is thrown for 1 or 2 customers, I see multiple rollback messages, and it seems like this is happening for each thread. Do transactions in camel routes with parallel processing work? Is there any other way to save customers in parallel to the DB in a single DB transaction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot do parallel work in the same transaction. The work must occur on the same thread.

Comment: Thank you Claus. I thought the same and thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: Hi, i am facing the same issue, did it get resloved by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `shareUnitOfWork()` in combination with your `parallelProcessing`.

As the Camel Documentation of the Splitter EIP mentions it will rollback the entire unit of work not only the sub units:

> When the Splitter is done, it checks the state of the shared unit of work and checks if any errors occurred. And if an error occurred it will set the exception on the Exchange and mark it for rollback. The error handler will yet again kick in, as the Exchange has been marked as rollback and it had an exception as well. No redelivery attempts is performed (as it was marked for rollback) and the Exchange will be moved into the dead letter queue.

see [Sharing Unit of work](http://camel.apache.org/splitter.html) chapter in the link.